# Gnuplot countours with discrete data points and dgrid3d

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am trying to plot some experimental data points (defined by x, y, and z) and and some "iso-z" lines. To plot contour lines, the data need to be in a grid format. I tried to follow proposed elsewhere, where by means of dgrid3d the experimental, nongrid data, are converted by interpolation into grid points, and use these new data points to draw the contour lines.

The script looks as follows:

```
reset

set term pdf color enhanced font 'Arial, 18' size 13.5cm,9.2cm
set out 'phasediag.pdf'

#Here I convert the data points, stored in 1f.dat into a grid format. 
set table '1f-grid.dat'
set dgrid3d 50,50 
splot '1f.dat' u 3:4:2 
unset table

#Here I would like to draw the countour lines, to be used after in the plot. 
set contour base
set cntrparam level auto 5
unset surface
set table 'cont.dat'
splot '1f-grid.dat'
unset table

# Load the palette color definition. 
load 'parula.pal'

set logscale cb
set cbrange[1e5:1e9]
set format cb '10^{%1.1T}'
set cblabel 'Mw / g mol^{-1}' offset 2.5,0

set format x '%1.1f'
set format y '%1.1f'
set label '1{/Symbol F}' at 0.4,6.3
set label '2{/Symbol F}' at 2.15,3


plot[0:2.7][2.5:7] '1f.dat' u 3:4:2 with points pt 5 palette, '2f.dat' u 3:2 with points pt 7 lc rgb "black"

set out
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I try to draw the contour lines in the cont.dat file:

```
 Warning: Cannot contour non grid data. Please use "set dgrid3d".
```

The error surprises me a bit, as the data produced in the first where produced using dgrid3d and are in grid format.

By commentig out the section in which the contour lines should have been drown, I get the following output: 
[image: Output file without the contour lines I would like to have]

I would simply draw some lines at constant z-values. Any hint for that?

Thanks in advance,
Leo

Comment: Can you please provide your data file?